# About a diophantine equation related to Fermat’s theorem n=3 case

Tags: number-theory

Lets say for some $x, y,N$ which are integers
$$5x^6-4y^3=N^2$$

From this if there must exist another pair if integers satisfying $5x^2-4y^3=N^2$ (where this $x,y,N$) are different fromthe first one , can we assert that there is no solution in integers to this equation?

Comment: What about $x=y=N=1$? That's a solution in integers. Do you mean there are not *two* such solutions? Please make clear what your question is.

Comment: Yes except for that case i think

Comment: Actually this q isrelated to another question in which x=y=N=1 gives a trivial solution

Comment: Just curious-- what is the other question yours is related to? [note that would give your question some "context" which is appreciated on this site.]

Comment: Is it possible to add pictures here?

Comment: Sorry i am new here

Comment: Why are there two different equations? One is in first statement and other in the second paragraph.

Comment: Well , as far as i am concerned lets say 5x^6-4y^3=N^2

Comment: Then ,4x^3-4y^3=(N-x^3)(N+x^3), from which N-x^3 is of form 2M , then adding M in to the equation, x^6-y^3=M^2+Mx^3 , from which x^3=M+-sqrt(M^2+(M^2+y^3) and i think discriminant also has to be integer squared

Comment: OK so to be clear you're asking whether this has any integer solution other than $1,1,1$ ? Also do you want only positive integers? Because the cube could be negative otherwise which may make a solution.

Comment: Yeah , i think negative is also okay

Comment: Please add your comments to the post as this provides context and prevents closure.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are infinitely many solutions to this equation in $\mathbb{Z}$. What you have is a curve
$$5x^6− 4 y^3 - z^2 =0 $$
in $\mathbb{P}(1,2,3)$. This is in fact an elliptic curve with Weierstrass equation
$$y^2 + y = x^3 + 1$$
which has rank $1$. For example, from the generator, we obtain the point $[x,y,N] = [4,-4,144]$. We can get some crazier ones. Some Magma code to verify this is below

```
P<x,y,N> := ProjectiveSpace(Rationals(), [1,2,3]);

C := Curve(P, 5*x^6 - 4*y^3 - N^2);

E, phi := EllipticCurve(C, C![1,1,1]);
_, phi := IsInvertible(phi);
Generators(E);
phi($1[1]);
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to add a picture?